# Can't change datatype of dataframe column to int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that refuses to convert to int from object for a number of columns.

The dataframe looks like:

```
  Body  Q2 2019   Q3 2019
0    A       50      93.0
1    B      NaN     228.0
2    C      186     180.0
3    D       35       NaN
4    E      344     555.0
```

where the column types are:

```
Body               object
Q2 2019            object
Q3 2019            object
```

I am trying to convert all column except for `Body` to int and coercing `NaN` value to `'-'`

so the output would look like:

```
  Body  Q2 2019   Q3 2019
0    A       50        93
1    B        -       228
2    C      186       180
3    D       35         -
4    E      344       555
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
df.fillna('-')
df.iloc[df.columns != 'Body'] = pd.to_int(df.iloc[df.columns != 'Body'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: so the `NaN` are actually strings? like `'NaN'` ? because you say the dtype is object, so just replace should work, `df.replace('NaN','-')`

Comment: try `df.fillna('-', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[['Q2 2019', 'Q3 2019']] = df[['Q2 2019','Q3 2019']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df[['Q2 2019', 'Q3 2019']] = df[['Q2 2019','Q3 2019']].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

or

```
df[['Q2 2019', 'Q3 2019']] = df[['Q2 2019','Q3 2019']].astype(int,errors="ignore")
df[['Q2 2019', 'Q3 2019']] = df[['Q2 2019','Q3 2019']].fillna(value='-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, what's the exact error output you get?

To use `df.iloc[]` for filtering on *columns*, remember to use `df.iloc[:,"column_name"]` and not `df.iloc["column_name"]`. Indeed, that tells `pandas` to keep all *rows*.

I'd go for explicit calls to your columns, and casting:

```py
df["Q2 2019"] = df["Q2 2019"].astype(int, errors="coerce")
df["Q3 2019"] = df["Q3 2019"].astype(int, errors="coerce")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to fill NaN with '-'

```
df.fillna(value='-',inplace=True)
```

and other then this if you notice Q3 2019, its corresponding row is started as float value 93.0,

```
Q3 2019
0 93.0
1 228.0
2 180.0
3 NaN
4 555.0
```

because of this all values are showing as float, consider changing the first value as int in `dataframe`, then python will treat all values as int instead of converting all of them in float

Note: if in any corresponding row of particular column has one float value then whole column will be converted to float.